# Barcode scanner as a NSObject subclass

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a barcode scanner in swift as a  `NSObject`  subclass, but I am having trouble firing the

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
```

delegate method. Here is my Class code.

```
class CKScanner: NSObject, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

//test
var delegate: AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate?

var frame: CGRect
//UPC Scan properties
let avSession:AVCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
let avDevice:AVCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)

var avInput:AVCaptureDeviceInput?
var avOutput:AVCaptureMetadataOutput?
var avPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var scannedUPC: NSString
{
    get {
        return self.scannedUPC
    }
}

required init(_frame: CGRect, _parentView: CALayer) {
    frame = _frame

    super.init()

    startScanning(_parentView)
}

func startScanning(_parentLayer: CALayer) {
    println("started scanning")
    var error: NSError?

    avInput = AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: avDevice, error: &error)
    if error != nil {
        println("Error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    if avSession.canAddInput(avInput!) {
        avSession.addInput(avInput!)
    }

    avPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: avSession)
    if avPreviewLayer != nil {
        avPreviewLayer!.frame = frame
        avPreviewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        _parentLayer.addSublayer(avPreviewLayer!)
    }
    avOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
    avOutput!.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
    if avSession.canAddOutput(avOutput!) {
        avSession.addOutput(avOutput!)
        avOutput!.metadataObjectTypes = avOutput!.availableMetadataObjectTypes
    }
    else {
        println("cant add output")
    }

    avSession.startRunning()

}

//scanner was able to scan a barcode
 func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {}
```

In my ViewController, I call

```
var scanner = Scanner(frame: frame, _parentLayer: layer)
```

I also tried to set the delegate in my ViewController instead of in the Scanner class, but with no luck.

And yes, I do include `AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate` at the top of my file to set the  `scanner.delegate = self`  correctly.

Comment: Hi Laurent, I also have created same NSObject for barcode scanning. I am able to see barcode in Video option but - (void)captureOutput:didOutputMetadataObjects:fromConnection: is not getting called. I have set queue = dispatch_get_main_queue(). But it is not working. Have you faced same issue in Objective C?

Comment: No, I've implemented it in Objective-C and the delegate method gets called like it is supposed to. I've only encountered the problem in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

What if you set metadataObjectTypes specifically to

```
[AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code]
```

Any difference?

Comment: No, unfortunately that doesn't work either. I had it implemented in objective-c and was working fine, but no luck in Swift. I also found this project  [https://github.com/yeahdongcn/RSBarcodes_Swift]. I tried to see if he did anything different, but can't seem to spot anything that would matter (except maybe that he is subclassing UIViewController and not NSObject